# Double Blind Entry (Two Pass Verification) for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

Are there JQuery features that would help put together a double blind entry `<input>`?

Basically, an input that requires the exact same text to be entered twice (in the same input box).  If they don't match, then the input is cleared (as if they had entered nothing).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a framework that has the core functionalities for querying the DOM tree, making animations & etc. It hasn't any UI controls.

Meanwhile there's other library named jQueryUI. It has some popular UI controls, but there isn't such control in it, too.

I think you should write it by yourself.